# Throw checked exception when Enum constant name length is greater than 10 characters?

Tags: java, enums

How do I throw an checked exception preventing compiling the code if one of my Enum constant name lenght is greater than 10 characters ?

Comment: You don't get to throw exceptions at compile time.

Comment: Write your own compiler :)

Comment: Annotate the enum and use a annotation processor to check constant names of annotated enums.

Comment: Hi fabian, please can you provide an example ?

Comment: @talx How about you research that topic yourself? And then if you get stuck, post a different question. It won't be trivial for fabian to post an example of that.

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve?  What would happen if a constant had say 11 characters?

Answer (score 2):

Probably the most practical solution is to use a Java style checker, such as [Checkstyle](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/). Then use a build tool, such as Maven, which can prevent a build from succeeding if the style checks fail.

This allows you to then check all manner of things, including enum length. Although you may need to write your own checker for that - it sounds a little specific.

Comment: +1 checkstyle allows you to define the format enum constants (and other variable names) must follow, including length.

Answer (score 0):

You can't enforce such restriction during compile time because the Java Language Specification does not restrict the lengths of the identifiers ([source](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html)):

> A variable's name can be any legal identifier — an unlimited-length sequence of Unicode letters and digits...

*(Note: the class file format however does pose a limit which is about 64K but it's not a JLS restriction.)*

The most you can do is throw an `Exception` at runtime if a declared name is too long, for example in the enum's constructor:

```
enum Fruit {
    APPLE,
    BANANA,
    STRAWBERRIES;

    private Fruit() {
        if (name().length()>10)
            throw new RuntimeException("Too long name: " + name());
    }
}
```

Also note that `Enum` constructors can only throw unchecked exceptions.